# How do I convert JSON Array to Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I got this JSON Array in a variable named jsonObject:

```
    jsonObject = {
    "log": [{
        "date": "15/09/2016",
        "time": "15:35:56",
        "temp": "16.0",
        "humidity": "95.0"
    }, {
        "date": "15/09/2016",
        "time": "15:35:59",
        "temp": "30.0",
        "humidity": "61.0"
    }, {
        "date": "15/09/2016",
        "time": "15:36:03",
        "temp": "30.0",
        "humidity": "60.0"
    }]
}
```

My goal is to iterate over it and place the data in a table and to do this I want the JSON Array as a normal array in Javascript. I have found many code examples on this, but none of them take into account the name of the array in this case "log". Anyone know how I can get rid of the name and just get an array? I could make the JSON array itne a string, substring it and then convert it into a JSON Array again and then convert it to a Array, but it feels very ineffeficent. Perhaps there is a way to create a 2D array of the JSON Array as a string but I don't know how.

Comment: [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Comment: How EXACTLY does your jsonObject look like ... more like `jsonObject = {...}` or more like `jsonObject = "{...}"`???

Comment: It looks exactly like the code above, I will edit it now.

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof jsonObject)` give you? If it is `string` then it is JSON, if `object` then it's a plain old Javascript object.

Comment: Re edit: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/ — There is absolutely no JSON in your question.

Comment: Interesting enough is the example on the Wikipedia link a string without quotes around it. So it is (optically) equivalent to what the OP originally posted. It is not totally clear that there is a difference when working with Javascript specifically

Comment: But on the wiki we know that they are talking about a human readable string.

Answer (score 1):

JSON objects *are* javascript variables. If you want log, just grab log.

```
jsonObject = {
    "log": [{
        "date": "15/09/2016",
        "time": "15:35:56",
        "temp": "16.0",
        "humidity": "95.0"
    }, {
        "date": "15/09/2016",
        "time": "15:35:59",
        "temp": "30.0",
        "humidity": "61.0"
    }, {
        "date": "15/09/2016",
        "time": "15:36:03",
        "temp": "30.0",
        "humidity": "60.0"
    }]
}
logArray = jsonObject.log
```

Comment: "JSON objects are javascript variables" — They are not. http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: in this case he is right because the OP said that it's a `JSON Array in a variable named jsonObject`

Comment: If you omit the first sentence (or rewrite it to something like `You already have an object literal called jsonObject`) this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the array, try something like this:

```
var jsonObj = {
        "log": [{
            "date": "15/09/2016",
            "time": "15:35:56",
            "temp": "16.0",
            "humidity": "95.0"
        }, {
            "date": "15/09/2016",
            "time": "15:35:59",
            "temp": "30.0",
            "humidity": "61.0"
        }, {
            "date": "15/09/2016",
            "time": "15:36:03",
            "temp": "30.0",
            "humidity": "60.0"
        }]
    };


 var jsonArr = jsonObj['log'];

 for(var i in jsonArr){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonArr[i]));
 }
```

Comment: This gives me each row, how about if I want a specific value, say I'm looking for the key "time" and it's value "15:35:59" It's mostly the value I am interested in.

Comment: Instead of jsonArr[i], include the key also like this : 
`console.log(jsonArr[i]['time']);`